# How to read /dev/tty in WSL2?

Tags: wsl-2, windows-11, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to read the terminal from the code, but `/dev/tty` returns empty.

```
    FILE *fp = fopen("/dev/tty", "r");
    if (!fp)
        return NULL;
```

The file pointer is just null:

[image]

If I just type `tty` in the terminal, I get this:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/7
$ echo "blah" > /dev/tty
blah
$ ls -rtl /dev/tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 5, 0 Feb  7 14:57 /dev/tty
```

Which seems to be working fine...? But doesn't seem to work in the code, does anyone else experienced this before and could perhaps give me a quick pointer?

I've checked this WSL issue but doesn't look like mine is related to the permission.
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/617

Thanks!

Comment: Works for me pasted verbatim from your post (when running in OpenSUSE running in WSL2). What `ls -la /dev/tty` return for you? Who's the owner of the file? Is it `rw` x3?

Comment: @orhtej2 The owner already there in the original post, and yeah, all `rw` x3

Comment: Ah but see, the owning group is `root` for you and it's `tty` for me. Try running `chgrp tty /dev/tty` perhaps?

Comment: @orhtej2 the group is now `tty` but is still the same, the `fp` is just `0x0`.

Comment: It's a known bug apparently although I'm yet to figure out what [the solution](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3351#issuecomment-1073038774) means.

Comment: With a bit more reading there's no actual `tty` assigned to WSL debugging session, as per [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1772).